# Autofocus on form inputs within list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and the inputs are in list items so as to display each input one at a time as the user enters information. I can not get autofocus to work. When the user clicks enter, the current input slides out and the next one slides in but does not have the cursor in the field.

```
    <div class="page" id="page-contact">
            <div class="fs-form-wrap" id="fs-form-wrap">
                <form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off">
                    <ol class="fs-fields">
                        <li>
                            <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name?</label>
                            <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" name="q1" type="text" placeholder="Joe Web" required/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">What's your email address?</label>
                            <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q2" name="q2" type="email" placeholder="jweb@dev.com" required/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q4">Leave me a note here</label>
                            <textarea class="fs-anim-lower" id="q4" name="q4" placeholder="Describe here"></textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ol><!-- /fs-fields -->
                    <button class="fs-submit button button--nuka" type="submit">Ready? submit</button>
```

This js didnt work and Im not sure why

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fs-anim-upper').on('keypress', function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    switch($(this).attr('id')){
                        case 'q2':
                        $('#q2').focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;
                        case 'q3':
                        $('#q3').focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code

#### Issue: wrong selector

You have now:

```
$('.fs-anim-upper').on('keypress', function(e) {
```

These are the `labels` in your html not the `inputs`. Change it to:

```
$('.fs-anim-lower').on('keypress', function(e) {
```

#### Issue: most probably wrong `id's`

```
 case 'q2': 
  $('#q2').focus();
  e.preventDefault();
  break;
 case 'q3':
  $('#q3').focus();
  e.preventDefault();
  break;
```

This means, when you press enter give focus to yourself.. I think you want:

```
case 'q1':
    $('#q2').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
    break;
case 'q2':
    $('#q4').focus(); // <--- Note that you have q4 in html, not q3
    e.preventDefault();
    break;
```

---

See here for a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mm6gc9a/7/